# How can I pass variable number of arguments to method2 from method1 that takes a variable number of arguments?

Tags: objective-c, arguments

Assume that we have methods:

```
-(instancetype) initWithElements:(id)firstElement, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
+(instancetype) objWithElements:(id)firstElement, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
```

I understand, how to work with variable number of arguments in `-initWithElements:`, but I don't understand how to pass variables from `-objWithElements:` to `-initWithElements:`.

I mean, I want to write something like:

```
+(instancetype) objWithElements:(id)firstElement, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION {
    return [[[self] initWithElements:ELEMENTS] autorelease];
}
```

Is it even possible?

The only solution for my problem I see is to store arguments in array and use helper method that will init object with given array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, in C (and Objective-C), it is not possible to pass down variadic arguments.

The idiomatic solution is to get yourself an initializer that takes a `va_list`, make **that** as the designated initializer, and then call it from every other method. From within a variadic method, this would look like:

```
- (instancetype)initWithVarargs:(id)first, ...
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, first);
    id obj = [self initWithFirst:first VAList:args];
    va_end(args);
    return obj;
}
```

and here's a designated initializer that takes a `va_list` argument:

```
- (id)initWithFirst:(id)first VAList:(va_list)args
{
    id obj;
    while ((obj = va_arg(args, id)) != nil) {
        // do actual stuff
    }
    // the return self, etc.
}
```

j

Comment: I see. But is this really necessary to use `- (id)initWithFirst:(id)first VAList:(va_list)args` instead of `-(instancetype) initWithElementsImpl:(va_list)args`? I mean, what if user enters something like `[obj initWithVarargs:nil]`?

Comment: @RottenBrain I don't see your problem. The user only call methods that exist. If you don't declare `initWithVarargs:`, the user will get a compiler warning/error when attempting to call it. However, you most definitely **do want** to pass down the very first object to the method as well (you can't write methods and functions with variadic arguments only, one fixed argument is always necessary.)

Answer (score 6):

I would create two versions of each method; one which takes variable arguments (`...`) and another (where the actual implementation is) using `va_list`:

```
-(instancetype) initWithElements:(id)firstElement, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
-(instancetype) initWithElementsImpl:(va_list)va;
+(instancetype) objWithElements:(id)firstElement, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
+(instancetype) objWithElementsImpl:(va_list)va;
```

This will allow the `va_list` version to simply pass that parameter onto the other `va_list` method with no work at all.

The var args version (`...`) will use `va_start()` et al to create the `va_list` *object* to pass to the `va_list` version of the method.